# How to choose min value at pandas dataframe also save my string data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, min

I have a pandas dataframe, columns are string and value, if i use 'groupby', I will lose my data, how to write my code to save my data?

```
print(df)

tconst title bool   id  pair
t01    Blow  True   1   1
t02    Blow  False  1   4
t03    Fast  TRUE   2   2
t04    Fast  FALSE  2   2
t05    Storm True   3   9
```

If meet same 'id' ,I want to choose min value at 'pair'(ex:id=1),If meet same 'id' but 'pair' value are same, I want to save all of them(ex:id=2).

```
out:
tconst title  bool   id  pair
t01    Blow   True   1   1
t03    Fast   TRUE   2   2
t04    Fast   FALSE  2   2
t05    Storm  True   3   9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use, `groupby`, `transform` with `min` to find lowest value within a group, then create a boolean series to do boolean indexing:

```
df[df['pair'] == df.groupby('id')['pair'].transform('min')]
```

Output:

```
  tconst  title   bool  id  pair
0    t01   Blow   True   1     1
2    t03   Fast   True   2     2
3    t04   Fast  False   2     2
4    t05  Storm   True   3     9
```